# Java calculator

Tags: java, calculator, javac

I want to take a number the user enters and multiply it by a couple of different numbers I set but I can't figure out how to declare an integer and get it to play nicely with whatever number the user enters. I've tried writing

```
System.out.println("If you take" + stepsOne * firstNum + "steps in a 10 second interval, you could potentially achieve...");
```

and just about every variation I can think of but I keep getting error messages. Apparently javac hates me for some reason. :/

Also, whenever the greeting displays, there's no space between the data the user enters and my system.out.println stuff so if they enter the name "George" it comes out as "HelloGeorge". Not as big of an issue as the above but if you know how to fix that then have at it. :)

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator
{

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {   
        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int firstNum;
        firstNum = 6;   

        System.out.println ("Hello, my name is Bob. What is your name?");

        String userName = userInputScanner.nextLine();  

        System.out.println ("Hello," + userName +  ". How many steps do you take in a ten second interval?"); 

        String stepsOne = userInputScanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("If you take" + stepsOne + "steps in a 10 second interval, you could potentially achieve..."); 

        System.out.println ("Number of steps per minute:");
        System.out.println ("Number of steps per hour:");
      }

}
```

Comment: *"whenever the greeting displays in javac, there's no space between the data the user enters and my system.out.println"* - That's because you never put any, trying adding a trailing and leading space, `System.out.println ("Hello, " + userName +  ". How many steps do you take in a ten second interval?"); `

Comment: You're already using `Scanner`. Why not use `Scanner#nextInt`?

Answer (score 2):

There is a crucial difference between the *string* `123` and the *integer* `123` - the first is merely a sequence of characters, which have no mathematical meaning. You need to *parse* the string, meaning that you must construct an integer based on the characters of the string. There's a built-in method for this (although it's very interesting to do it yourself too): `Integer.parseInt()`.

```
String stepsOneString = userInputScanner.nextLine();
int stepsOne = Integer.parseInt(stepsOneString);
```

Now, `stepsOne` is an integer on which you can perform mathematical operations. However, `Integer.parseInt()` throws an *exception* that you'll need to handle. At this point in your course, I'm guessing that you're expected to use the built-in conversion capabilities of the `Scanner`:

```
int stepsOne = userInputScanner.nextInt();
```

This will essentially perform the two above steps for you.

I strongly recommend that you read up on the subject of *data types*, which will explain the above concepts.

Comment: Note that you should also use `Scanner#nextLine` to consume the line break entered by user after pressing Enter key.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: True, but it's only necessary if you want to use `next()` or `nextLine()` again to obtain a string.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a string representing a number, you can use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) to get an integer from it.

```
String stringSteps = userInputScanner.nextLine();
int steps = Integer.parseInt(stringSteps);
```

Here is a complete program with improved spacing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {   
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Hello, my name is Bob. What is your name?");

    String userName = userInputScanner.nextLine(); //Asks user name

    System.out.println("Hello, " + userName +
        ". How many steps do you take in a ten second interval?");

    String stringSteps = userInputScanner.nextLine();
    int steps = Integer.parseInt(stringSteps);

    System.out.println("If you take " + steps +
        " steps in a 10 second interval, you could potentially achieve...");

    System.out.println ("Number of steps per minute: " + (6 * steps));
    System.out.println ("Number of steps per hour: " + (60 * 6 * steps));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, I just want to take a number the user enters and multiply it by a couple of different numbers I set but I can't figure out how to declare an integer and get it to play nicely with whatever number the user enters. I've tried typing

First problem is `stepsOne` is `String`, so it can't be used to perform arithmetic on (at least not they type you're trying).  So you need to convert it to a `int`

```
int stepsOneInt = Integer.parseInt(stepsOne);
```

*nb: This will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the `String` can't be converted to a `int` value, so beware of that*

Now you can use it to perform other arithmetic tasks

```
System.out.println("If you take " + (stepsOneInt * firstNum) + " steps in a 10 second interval, you could potentially achieve...");
```

> Also, whenever the greeting displays in javac, there's no space between the data the user enters and my system.out.println stuff so if they enter the name "George" it comes out as "HelloGeorge". Not as big of an issue as the above but if you know how to fix that then have at it. :)

That's because you don't add any spaces before you print the value

```
System.out.println ("Hello, " + userName +  ". How many steps do you take in a ten second interval?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your issue...

You can't do stepsOne*firstNum as stepsOne is a String.
If stepsOne must be an int, just do this:

```
int stepsOne = userInputScanner.nextLine(); //Asks user a nb
```